# List has no attribute strip

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, strip

I'm reading from a file and storing each character in a two dimensional array. I'm trying to get rid of the '\n' that comes at the end of each line. My code so far is:

```
l = []
for i in range(5):
    l.append([])
f = open('file.txt','r')
count = 0
for line in f:
    for char in line:
        l[count].append(char)
    count += 1

f.close()

l[0].rstrip('\n')
```

I have tried instead of the `l[0].rstrip('\n')`:

`l = map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'), l)` and 
`l = [i.rstrip() for i in l ]`

Each of these return the error that list has no attribute strip (or rstrip). Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just not append `char` to `l[count]` if it's a `\n`? Lists don't have `strip()`, strings do. Are you trying to create a string in each `l[count]`, or really a list of single characters?

Comment: `strip` is for strings, so apply it to the string before you do the other work: `for char in line.strip():`

Comment: I've add an if statement before the `l[count].append(char)` to check if char is '\n' and got rid of the `l[0].rstrip('\n')` and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

`l` is a **list of lists**. So if you call `l[0].rstrip()` you can `rstrip()` on the sublist. But even if `strip()` would have worked, you would not have seen any difference since strings are immutable, and thus it will return a *new* string, not update the older one.

You can however easily use:

```
l[0] = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in l[0]]
```

to update only `l[0]`.

If you want to update all the sublists, you can use the following list comprehension:

```
l = [[x.rstrip('\n') for x in s] for s in l]
```

Furthermore the code for reading your file into memory is quite weird: it will only work if the file has less than six lines. You can use the following approach:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    l = [list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in f]
```

this replaces the entire code fragment in the question.